# Calling a method from a object that extends another object (not what you think it is)

Tags: java, minecraft

I have a question. How do you place a method in the deceleration of an object? Let me explain. What I’m making is a Minecraft network. All of the games we have to offer are their own class.

Example: CaptureTheFlag is its own object but it extends a class called arena.

Every game class extends the Arena class. So when these games are made, they are added to a hashmap (double, arena). When I iterate through these looking for a specific gamemode I need to be able to call the method for that gamemode for the player to join.

Example: CaptureTheFlag.join(player)

Every game has the same method called join and the same parameters but each one does different things because these are different games. So when I iterate through my hashmap and find the specific value (arena) I want to be able to call the Capture the flag join method like this:

```
Iterator<Entry<Double, Arena>> it = 
ArenaManager.local_arenas.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Double, Arena> pair = it.next();
        if (pair.getKey().doubleValue() == game_mode) {



                pair.getValue().join(player)

        }

    }
```

Please note thats not the full code. (I'm on a phone typing this)

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Just declare an abstract method in `Arena` with the same signature and you'll be able to call it on any instance of `Arena`.

Comment: what is the problem if you declare the `join()` method in your super class and override it in each child class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: use an abstract method:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo {

    static class Player {
        private final String name;

        Player(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    static abstract class Arena {
        abstract void join(Player player);
    }

    static class CaptureTheFlagArena extends Arena {

        @Override
        void join(final Player player) {
            System.out.printf("%s is joining a capture the flag game!%n", player);
        }
    }

    static class DominationArena extends Arena {

        @Override
        void join(final Player player) {
            System.out.printf("%s is joining a domination arena!%n", player);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints:
     * Bob is joining a domination arena!
     * Bob is joining a capture the flag game!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<Double, Arena> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(7d, new CaptureTheFlagArena());
        map.put(6d, new DominationArena());
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Arena> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().join(new Player("Bob"));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Solution 2: use an interface:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo {

    static class Player {
        private final String name;

        Player(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    interface Joinable {
        void join(Player player);
    }

    static abstract class Arena implements Joinable {

    }

    static class CaptureTheFlagArena extends Arena {

        @Override
        public void join(final Player player) {
            System.out.printf("%s is joining a capture the flag game!%n", player);
        }
    }

    static class DominationArena extends Arena {

        @Override
        public void join(final Player player) {
            System.out.printf("%s is joining a domination arena!%n", player);
        }
    }

    static class ChessGame implements Joinable {

        @Override
        public void join(final Player player) {
            System.out.printf("%s is joining a chess game!%n", player);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints:
     * Bob is joining a domination arena!
     * Bob is joining a capture the flag game!
     * Bob is joining a chess game!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<Double, Joinable> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(7d, new CaptureTheFlagArena());
        map.put(6d, new DominationArena());
        map.put(2d, new ChessGame());
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Joinable> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().join(new Player("Bob"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought this would have been more complicated for some reason. This has really helped! Thanks!